# How to use &:symbol notation with map and a custom method?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def add_one(el)
  el += 1
end

p [1,2,3].map { |el| add_one(el) }
p [1,2,3].map(&:add_one)
```

When I try the `&:add_one`, I get `map: private method add_one called for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`

What am I missing here? How can I call add_one with the &: notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` notation that converts a symbol to a proc doesn't work like that. It creates a block where the argument passed to it is the *receiver* of the method call, not the argument.

```
p [1,2,3].map(&:add_one)
# is equivalent to this
p [1,2,3].map { |el| el.add_one }
```

> How can I call add_one with the &: notation?

You don't. You simply wouldn't use the shorthand form in this case. There's no reason to.

Comment: Interesting. So, is there any way to use that notation and pass arguments?

Comment: Not really, no. You could probably do some complicated override of `Symbol#to_proc` to get something like that, but that'll get quite tricky. Why are you set on using the shorthand form?

Comment: I am just experimenting... Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do something similar to `&:` for a method on `self` using the [`method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-method) method:

```
def add_one(el)
  el += 1
end

p [1,2,3].map(&method(:add_one))
# [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Active Record relation
for example for User with fields :name, :age, :address
you can use it:

```
users = User.all
```

so you can use &:...

```
users.map(&:name) # => ['John', 'Oleg', 'Egor']
```

same

```
users.map { |user| user.name }
```